# insert values from jQuery datepicker + timepicker to MySQL datetime datatype using Codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datetimepicker

I want to insert values from `jQuery datepicker + timepicker` to MySQL `datetime` datatype using Codeigniter, but the problem is that it inserts (1970-01-01 01:00:00).

this is my javascript code:

```
// Datetimepicker
$('#birthday').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss'
});
```

this is my the value in my input:

```
1940-09-18 17:18:21
```

and this is my input:

```
<input type="text" name="birthday" value="" id="birthday" class="ltr hasDatepicker" maxlength="250" tabindex="3">
```

this is controller:

```
function add()
     {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('birthday', 'birthday', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s is required');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        { 
            $user_Id = $this->user_model->add($_POST);   
        }

     }
```

and this is my code in model:

```
function add($options = array())
{

    $options = array(

    'name' => $this->input->post('Name'),

    'birthday' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->input->post('birthday'))),

    );


    $this->db->insert('mg_field', $options);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

but unfortunately it 1970-01-01 01:00:00 in to the database! what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: hi in add function don't use date function to create a new date, you already formatting it, just give 'birthday'=>this->input->post('birthday')

Comment: what does `var_dump($this->input->post('birthday'))` show?

Comment: @umefarooq, you were right! I was doing it wrong!

Answer (score 2):

If your input value is  exactly similar format 1940-09-18 17:18:21  then

Change your code

```
'birthday' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->input->post('birthday'))),
```

to

```
'birthday' => $this->input->post('birthday'),
```

I hope you will success.

Dear, down voter understand his input.